# What to do with same answers from one user on multiple questions

Tags: discussion, answers, users

I just noticed a user who posted the same answer to some old questions.

The answers look like "You can use this JavaScript library to solve your problem" and some code how it would work with that.

I don't know if it really solves the problem, but it looks like promotion for his library. He registered today and this library also seems to be not older than a few days.

So I'm not sure if the answers should be flagged as spam or something.
I'm also not sure to post the link to the users profile here.

Comment: what about flagging it with `The same with` another?

Comment: you mean as 'other (needs moderator attention)'? I try to avoid this to not making them more work as necessary. But maybe this is a case for the moderators?

Comment: Is it the same or only the same pattern? In the first case, the mods will get an auto-flag. In the second, check how duplicate the questions are (chance for close-dupe?), how may such answers he posted and how big a chunk of his posts that is, whether he properly discloses his affiliation, and raise spam-flags if needed. (If you are still unsure, just raise *one* custom flag concisely and fully describing the issue you noticed).

Comment: two are differ only by a few characters. I have flaged now one of the answers for moderator attention.

Comment: Since it's clearly a spam account created only to spam for his new library, you may as well post his profile because it'll be deleted or suspended anyway.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Does the auto-flag apply to answers, or only to questions? I had mainly seen it mentioned in the context of questions before.

Comment: possible cross site duplicate of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions

Comment: It would definitely help to have links to the answers you're referring to in your question.

Comment: The auto flag definitely applies to answers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In general, assess each answer in the context of the question for which it is provided.

Whether distinct questions may have the same answer doesn't necessarily indicate that those questions are duplicates, and there's nothing wrong with a user providing what looks like "duplicate answers" to such non-duplicate questions, **as long as those answers actually are a reasonable attempt at answering these questions**.

It's hard to assess this particular case, since you haven't provided any link to the examples you have in mind. It also depends on the number of occurrences.

- Where the answer is on topic for the question, leave it be (and who knows, you might even upvote some of those answers if you think they're good answers for that question).
- It's only really a problem if the answers are quite off the mark and only very loosely related to the questions. The usual reasons to downvote of course apply in this case. If there's more than a few instances of these, it's worth flagging them.

If there's a mixed bag of these two types of cases, it can be tricky to indicate to the moderators which ones you think are appropriate, and which ones you think are not.

Answer (score 4):

From the [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) :

> If a large percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons.

You say the account is new as well as the advertised product, so it's clearly an account created for the sole purpose of spamming.

So flag it as spam, and let the mods **kill the account with fire**.

Comment: It all depends on the number. On a new account with say 5 or 6 answers mentioning that library (making close to 100% of these posts), there's hope that the user may be able to provide other less biased answers. If it becomes more systematic after a while, that would be different. Note that another good reason for a user to mention their project is when other unrelated users ask questions about that project, generally when the project becomes popular. These are the kind of expert users we generally want to keep, so there's a fine balance here.

Comment: @Bruno What bothers me is that the person created the account solely for advertising. If he already had an account, with some (hopefully good) content, it'll be less problematic.

Comment: It can make sense for a account to be partly "branded", especially when the user discloses it well. I don't necessarily mind that, and that gives some sort of authority w.r.t. the project. When it becomes a problem is when such users try to push repeatedly their products in answers that merely answer the questions (or are close to link-only answers).

Comment: @Bruno in this case the answers seem to be low-quality copy-pasta on some old questions, so the intent of that user is still malicious (to me anyway), he's just posting ads instead of genuinely helping people that have problems with his software.

Comment: Well, if this new library actually helps with the problems mentioned in those older questions, why not? (It sounds like these are not link-only answers, since they come with a short example too.) That's not necessarily malicious, it can be a genuine attempt to help.

Comment: @Bruno the copy-pasta makes it malicious IMO, but without looking at the concerned questions and answers we can only speculate.

Comment: @AndréDaniel: I disagree with that quote from the help center. If I made a new library that solved a common problem I would sure as heck go on StackOverflow and find relevant questions and post new answers referring people to my library. After all, it solves their problems. And if I didn't have an account then I would sure as heck make one. Just because I'm mentioning my product or website doesn't mean I'm here for the wrong reasons. I would just be trying to prevent people from reinventing the wheel.