# Has Stack Overflow gotten more strict on what counts as 'off-topic'?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, scope, close-reasons, downvote-reason

I've noticed this trend over the years. When I was younger my questions would be welcome nearly every time. Now I'm getting downvoted on almost everything I ask. Perhaps it's because of all the new Stack Exchange sites, but I'm not sure.

Is Stack Overflow becoming more strict?

Comment: Yes, as the traffic and size of the SE network has increased, SO's scope has tightened.

Comment: It's to do with the user-base too. At the start, most questions were on-topic, since the site needed as many questions and users as it could get. Now it is very popular, it can afford to be more fussy - and that is a good thing, as it keeps the quality level higher.

Comment: I quite like the use of the expression "*when I was younger*" coming from someone who has only been a member for a couple of years ;-)

Comment: @Bruno I was younger yesterday... nothing wrong with it :)

Comment: @halfer I must disagree with the conclusion "it keeps the quality level higher", I don't think that's a given. There are questions that people would find value in that are driven from the site, along with the people who ask them who would have asked (or answered) better questions in the future.

Comment: I think that having Triage reviews increases the amount of Off Topic flagging as it's easier to do from there; I think people are no more strict, but find it easier to flag their strictness.

Comment: No, SO and SF are very hostile. SU and physics, too. Math SE and Unix SE are friendly. Beta and smaller sites are mostly better.

Comment: @Bruno StackOverflow is only **7 years** old, so basically **nobody** can say _"when I was younger"_ ;)

Comment: @Giosco We were all younger 7 years ago.

Comment: @DonRoby Except if you were travelling around for 7 years at speed of light ..  BTW, you can feel much younger at 40+ than with 20. Life becomes more relaxed and fulfilled over time.

Comment: @Mark: I don't think that's a given either. The theory is that if say, good discursive questions were permitted, the quality level would rise. But that might also encourage a rise in bad discursive questions too. I suppose those could be closed for other reasons, such as 'unclear', but that's still more LQ to close. A knock-on effect might also be that questions turn into conversations, which may have limited quality value for people seeking Q&A.

Comment: Do you have a particular category of off-topic question that should not be closed, so as not to drive away certain categories of user?

Comment: I agree that it's got stricter, but on the other hand the need for new questions and answers has got smaller. I get answers for most common programming issues I run into just by search-engining them, and usually the top ones (and often the best) are from SO. tl;dr if you ask or give an answer to a question it better be good.

Comment: As the 'population' of SO increased, everything increased accordingly (crap questions  AND crap moderators).

Comment: @Giosco et. al. - If i'm 24 (with professional experience) now and was 18 (with high school experience) when i joined (with a different account), it's probably fair to use the phrase i did... We could always go ask 'Must you own a rocking chair and cane to use the phrase *when i was younger*' on the English L&U site, i'm sure they would be accepting of the question ;)

Comment: I have to agree with @peterh. I've been using this site for awhile, and it does indeed seem to me it's become quite hostile. I don't even ask questions anymore, there's no point.

Comment: I was wondering about a trend on the other side of the coin: is the quality of question asking going down as the site gains popularity. It feels like there's a growing number of questions which are nothing more than a homework question pasted into the textarea, maybe appended with "plz help quickly!". Such new members certainly don't seem to be attempting to make an effort to join a community; they just give the impression of being in a hurry to get work done for them with as little of their own effort as is possible.

Comment: Certainly as the strictness has risen I've spent a lot more time refining my questions before asking. In fact, on more than one occasion that refining has led me to find the answer before I even get the question asked.

Comment: I'm voting this as off topic just because it seems like the ironic thing to do (: jk.

Comment: @pjmorse and do you still put them up? I've been finding the same - I find the answer as I refine the question - and sometimes if I'm in pressed for time I don't then put it up, which is a shame..

Comment: Yes!!! It has gotten stricter, largely due to shared-contagious-subtlity-lacking-mentality-caused-by-a-meger-few

Comment: @drevicko Often by the time I've refined to the point of answering it myself, the scope is so narrow I don't bother posting. I could go both ways on that.

Comment: @pjmorse yeah, I know what you mean, though narrow scope isn't always bad. I often end up asking myself "would I have found this and would it have saved me time?". If 'yes', then probably someone else will too. That said, some things are rediculously narrow.. It can come down to "is it really worth the bother?"

Answer (score 89):

There's cycles on these things. My journey as a Stack Overflow user started out fairly laid back - if I could chip in an answer to a question, I would, and not particularly care about the topicality.

As time has passed though, I've become hardened by a torrent of poor questions - it's not the odd one or two, but a steady stream of "do my work for me", "this is my homework, what is the answer" and some that make by brain ache trying to untangle what they're asking.

So my tolerance has slipped, and so I'm faster on the downvote or close buttons than I was when I first started. I tend to reserve my question-disentangling brain for when it's clearly someone who's trying, but suffering from English being a second language, or are genuinely trying to understand a concept, but can't quite articulate it.

That's pretty subjective I know. But personally - I think I can tell the difference between someone who's not working in their primary language, and someone who's just too lazy. And I think being too lazy to ask for free help effectively is just ... well, rather discourteous.

So yes - I can well imagine that the average user on Stack Overflow has followed the same journey - you start full of good will, but then realise that encourages help vampires and clutters up our site with junk, because if you reward "lazy" you promote more lazy.

Comment: I went through similar phases, but then went back to a more relaxed mode, at least depending on the kind of "off-topic" (there are actually multiple sub-categories). In particular, I'm still rather tolerant for question about a [subject that is borderline on/off-topic](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266612/372643) (as long as the question is answerable and can apply to a development context) and I [don't hunt for duplicates too harshly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270882/372643). That said, we all have different point of views.

Comment: Spot on, this.​

Comment: Realize that as SO grows, the number of people following this same cycle also grows, so it's ever easier to collect downvotes and close votes just by sheer numbers.

Answer (score 66):

Yes, it has. During the early days, due to the need to build awareness of the site and the lack of availability of other sites, the guidelines were much more lax in terms of what was considered on-topic. While quality standards existed, there wasn't a lot available to use as a measurement of what was a good (or not so good) question.

Now that there are so many other StackExchange sites available for specific types of questions (such as [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) for general computer/software questions), the guidelines have gotten more specific. So have the quality standards - it's a lot easier to judge a poor quality question when you have millions of good (or great) ones to compare it against, and a few million other users to help make that determination.

You can always find the current guidelines (which can and do change over time) in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) pages.

Comment: ... Just being smaller allowed being less strict. And also, there was less experience with what made a good post, and what wouldn't work on the SE Q&A-engine.

Answer (score 10):

My sense is that SO has indeed become more strict.

I was first attracted to this website because of its name. "Stack Overflow" -- indeed a nasty problem, which appears to suggest that you can seek help on any such things, whether you are getting a leak while programming in C, or were simply given an error message "Stack Overflow!" as in the old DOS-like environments. My guess is that others may be attracted to SO for similar reasons, as evidenced by many of the closed questions asked by new users and well-received closed questions that are 5 years old. Other sister websites are similarly called `MathOverflow` without a clear clue what is/can be overflowing in math.

Now the topic of SO seems to be much much narrower. Many veterans lecture people about their lack of understanding on what SO really is. What it really is, I think, is a moving target that changes over time.

The things that became off-topic, as far as I can remember, include general programming advice (too-broad), seeking a development library (off-topic), recommendation for books, help with debugging/diagnosis (off-topic), theoretical/algorithmic questions without code in a specific language, and so on.

So, my sense is, yes, SO is definitely becoming more strict in terms of what is on topic.

Comment: Actually, algorithmic questions are still on-topic. It's just different to ask a good one without any supporting code.

Comment: Help with debugging is off topic? Half the questions I see in the Java tag are about debugging code. And they are more likely to be answered than closed.

Comment: Debugging is fine. Debugging without, say, a specific error message, or without any code, or without anything to indicate expected functionality — not so muchly.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what it's been like in the past, but I recently had a question closed as "off-topic"; it got flagged within five minutes or so of me posting it, and I felt it was a very relevant question and not one prone to opinion-based answers. I asked specifically for possibilities which could be backed up with actual evidence.

It was not a good experience, especially for someone who's new to the site and trying to be an upstanding member of the community. I felt I had followed the guidelines, and the person who put me up for being closed was snarky and full of barely-veiled insults - and then he told ME to "be nice".

I almost didn't return to the Stack family of sites because I was so irritated, but I'm trying not to be put off my game by some knucklehead with a bone to pick. I still have the lingering question of why it was approved for closure...and I still don't understand the logic of declaring a relevant question requesting factual answers "off-topic" and saying that it perpetuates opinion-based argument, but whatever. I shall overcome, give the finger, and live to code another day.

Comment: Were the "factual answers" provable? Looking back at that closed question, i'd have to agree with the close reason. All we can do is speculate on why those bots would be hitting those forms with that data. The only way an answer would be backed by a fact would be if it was posted by the person who wrote the bot doing the spamming.

Comment: Hmm...I appreciate your answer, Kevin, even with a downvote lol :) My thought was that in asking for evidence, I was going to be receiving examples from people who have lived through the same scenario, and what the cause/result was.

Comment: @KevinB well, it sounds like a question that many would be interested in, though perhaps a rephrase along the lines of "these bots have been hitting my form - what can I do about it?". In any case, is there another venue for such a question?

Comment: There may be another stack exchange site where it would be more appropriate. Since it isn't a code related question, it doesn't really fit stackoverflow. There is no problem to solve. there is no answer, other than you're simply being hit by a web crawler who's sole purpose is to submit garbage/spam into unprotected forms, regardless of the form's purpose, possibly for spam purposes, or even vulnerability checking.

Answer (score -7):

Unfortunately, network communities tend to be more and more closed, and strict by time. It is because the ratio of the people who are here since years, is always bigger and bigger. And they tend to force the rules and customs invented by them, here, which are non-trivial, and sometimes even nonsense for a newbie.

The result is an inbred community where only an [uncritical, conformist attitude](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291017/april-2015-community-moderator-election-results/291158#291158) can provide longterm survival. People with creative or new ideas experience a constant downwind.

There is another structural problem, and this is that forcing these non-trivial, and sometimes even nonsense rules means the continuous, large-scale destruction of the content created by good-standing newbies. Normal people won't do this too long, it requires people *enjoying* that.

And it is not about the crap. It is about the high level content which would be ontopic on the common sense, but not on the non-trivial house rules. And it is about any idea or suggestion to [make things better](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/my-question-was-downvoted-closed-because-it-was-full-of-grammatical-mistakes-wh/291370).

Of course, there is a terrible mass of crap as well, but I am not talking about this. I am talking about an unfortunate social selection mechanism of the system.

The collective mentality of the community is going into a direction which is maybe [more destructive as needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UU9CF.jpg).

The only excuse is that the site stays against the siege of an overwhelming crap. Unfortunately, I can't see a solution against this. Maybe if the SE used a more strict control, it could help, but I think, they would risk to lose the voluntary work in the fight against the crap.

On my opinion, the best would be if a race would be created between the different SE sites. The fortunately growing number of the new SE sites are going into this direction. I think, a "doubly connected graph" should describe the topics of the sites of SE network - I understand on this, that practically every question would be ontopic on at least 2 different SE sites. So the users would slowly move from the worser sites to the more friendlier.

For example, the [unix SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com) is a very friendly, well-organized SE site, but it probably wouldn't be so if they didn't need to stay against the "concurrence" of the [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) (partially hostile) and the [serverfault](http://serverfault.com) (very hostile).

In case of the SO it would mean its parting into a network of smaller sites, smaller communities, who are racing with eachother for the (qualified) content and (qualified) users. I suggest to take part in the work of the [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com), you would make the world a little bit better place with that.

Comment: I remember what happened to a few very useful, but "off-topic" questions, that took an extraordinary amount of effort to preserve from the "rule enforcers". Then the policing of minor edits. In the end, it is just too much for regular users to resist the dominant culture and a whole lot of people who enjoy their influence derived from it, so the system is stuck with the people who embrace it.

Comment: "network communities tend to be more and more closed" true; Wikipedia faced the same "problem" long time ago.. http://www.psmag.com/books-and-culture/killed-wikipedia-93777

Comment: @prusswan Exactly. This "rule-enforcing" caused already the destruction of many important posts. I think, the control of the site should go into a direction, where this "closed circle mentality" won't be "profitable" any more.

Comment: @εEridani Yes. This phenomenon happened with irc chatrooms and on the usenet decades ago. The reputation/voting system of the SE works against this, but I think, in its current form it is not enough. I think, the worst is that sometimes even some like a "personal cult" is visible here.

Comment: I think the theory of self-reinforcing codes of conduct that makes for a conservative atmosphere, wary of change, is an interesting one. However, I don't think your post shows that such a model applies to Stack Overflow - there is plenty of opinion here and no evidence. How can you be sure that a permissive attitude to topicality would not result in a drop in quality? Perhaps your example of conformism is just someone honestly congratulating a long-serving moderator for their work? What nonsense rules do you think are destructive of good material written by new users? Can you show examples?

Comment: @εEridani that seems to make sense. In the long run, the same rules that make things "work" can also be their downfall, as much as dynasties rise and fall. Maybe this should just be accepted as the natural order of things

Comment: @peterh I think another aspect of the problem is that some people are treating this like a special kind of facebook..they are more interested in participating in the system and carrying out its rules, than the original purpose the system is meant to serve (building a pool of knowledge). Don't see any solution in sight though (and maybe to majority of the users, this is not a problem so no solution is needed)

Comment: @prusswan You have right. I never said anything about them except that these posts don't deserve survival. I think, there is a problem that the knowledge pool building isn't really well communicated. And the initial idea behind SO was something between a help forum and the wikipedia. Although it is not a facebook, it is more "forum-like" as the wiki, on my opinion. The primary motivation of the questioners that they want a help in their programming tasks. And the answerers is that they want to collect reputation.

Comment: @halfer Unfortunately, it is very hard to provide evidence, because only 10k+ users can see the deleted content of the site. And unfortunately, I would be very happy if we could initiate a really productive debate about the always narrowing topic of the site, but unfortunately, it will result only around 20 downvotes in this answer, and an impractical comment-chat in 100kbytes of length. The real definition of the bad rules are anyways very simple: every rule which closes out content considered about programming on the common sense, but not on the rules of the site.

Comment: I think that debate has been had, to be honest - though do have it again if you think there is something new to be said. If you are downvoted, it does not matter - votes do not affect your rep score here. I suspect you'll need to try to be more generous of spirit though - as it stands, between you and prusswan, I see some of the negativity that you criticise the sites for: uncritical, conformist, hostile, personality cult, inbred, collective mentality, destructive...

Answer (score -7):

While the whole site is really amazing, I truly believe that some of the creators and moderators are so totally connected to Stack Overflow, that they have become routine-blinded and are already suffering from a kind of tunnel-vision.

Consider this: Some have more than 100k "points", one moderator even has 300k: Assume you need 1 hour for 10 points, then these are 30,000 hours ... The site is 7 years old, these means 11 hours per day, 7 years long ...

What I want to say: Here is a high "tension level", the mods have built a big respectable system, but in the same moment, they cannot empathize anymore with newbies. So what is just a routine click for them, is shock and horror for a newbie.

I honestly recommend some mods to take a long vacation: Minimum 6 months of world travel on a sailing boat, but please without a computer at hand.

At one side it is great to dedicate a life to creating such a amazing system; on the other side, the world is big and has a lot to offer, so I recommend to look around to get some distance and some fresh ideas.

Comment: 100K users will often get 100-200 points a day on old questions (i.e. for doing nothing new). The points/hour one earns on the site is so variable, it's not worth hazarding a guess at.

Comment: "[mods] cannot empathize anymore with newbies" - you're welcome to whatever view you like, but that statement is contentious. Closing/downvoting bad questions is not the same thing as being unfriendly to new users.

Comment: While I certainly sympathise with your view, it is off I think. I have earned hundreds of fake unicorn points within minutes at times, and by now my rep is pretty much in cruise control. One does *not* need to spend virtually every waking moment on the site to get a high rep. And while there's certainly a chance to develop tunnel vision, I think the mods of this site are overall extraordinarily self-critical. I rather see a lot of misunderstood tunnel vision in mid-level newbies, who *think* they are acting according to the rules but are missing the underlying intent.

Comment: @halfer My statement is intended for reflection. I have been working 10 years as a C++ trainer. I loved that, but one day I noticed that I was in "different spheres", and not able anymore to understand newbies. I was not able to provide quality help anymore. I decided then to do something else.

Comment: Rep inflation happens to everyone, which is one of the more obvious deficiencies of the system. Another deficiency is the over reliance on moderators to moderate stuff. Sometimes they can become part of the problem (or make it worse) while in a position of influence, and I suspect the influence is so attractive that some may seek it as a means to validate their "success" at this system, if reputation is not enough. (Yes, some people do want to "succeed" at this system, regardless of what "success" may mean)

Comment: @prusswan In the 21st century, "success" is defined as "likes" . At least for some.

Answer (score -26):

Not only has it gotten stricter, but there is very apparent unfriendliness and I would even say hostility toward newbies.  A proper response to an improper question should consist of an explanation why this is not a good a question or even better a "Here's an article you might want to start reading to get better knowledge about this."  Downvoting should be kept to a minimum.

But more often than not, responses are combined with downvotes, which discourages people from becoming a part of the community.

Comment: I think you mistake the site's purpose. You aren't contracting for paid tutoring when posting a question. And you seem oblivious of what votes are for: Rating content, not enticing new users.

Comment: Case at hand, ladies and gentlemen.

Comment: I saw a cracking question a few weeks ago. It was well-presented, well-thought-out, clearly researched, and had a specific focus. It was posted by a brand new user, with very little programming experience. And do you know what? _He got NO "hostility" whatsoever._ It baffles me that people keep asserting there's some sort of automatic hostility and unfriendliness towards newcomers: _there isn't_. There is automatic hostility and unfriendliness to lazy slobs who post total nonsense and somehow think everybody else should work to parse it. No.

Comment: If SO is getting stricter it's because we're seeing _more_ of the sort of nonsense you're spewing here, making us more and more tired.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit +100000 for "It baffles me that people keep asserting there's some sort of automatic hostility and unfriendliness towards newcomers: *there isn't* There is automatic hostility and unfriendliness to lazy slobs who post total nonsense and somehow think everybody else should work to parse it." This should be on every meta rant from now on.

Comment: Give me a break, guys.  Just look at the language you're using in your comments here, in Meta. "Oblivious, spewing, lazy, nonsense."  Yes, this is hostile.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET The problem with "off-topic" is that it encompasses are broad range of reasons for closure, and it seems the categories have become stricter, independently of the question quality. Another typical problem newcomers can have is not knowing what they don't know, which can lead to questions that look poor, without having anything to do with laziness.

Comment: *"Yes, this is hostile."* Nobody said it wasn't. Perhaps you should read those comments again.

Comment: @Dave, Somewhere I read "A proper response to an improper question should consist of an explanation why this is not a good a question" and I see a lot of explanation why this particular post is not aligned with SO goals and spreads some misconceptions. Unfortunately some people do not accept critique or disagreement in any form and insist that only positive feedback to be provided...

Comment: @Radiodef So should I start a new Meta question "Should we be assholes to people who ask poor questions?"

Comment: @Dave - that would be duplicate, and again downvotes/votes to close *are not* impolite or improper behavior as you seem to imply. And not personal either.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov.  Actually, the very first comment called me "oblivious," which is far from the most effective way to deliver constructive critique.  Being a good programmer is not an excuse for poor manners.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The problem is that general behavioural feedback that only consists of saying "bad dog" (more or less) is unlikely to lead to improved behaviour in subsequent questions. (That said, I would agree that there are a number of cases that are absolutely terrible, almost hopeless.)

Comment: @Dave: It was an observation. He said you _seem_ oblivious, which is objectively true. You're not helping matters by jumping to the victim card and blaming everybody else for being horrible people when you come here and attack hard-working volunteers armed only with half-truths and misunderstandings.

Comment: @Dave aren't you? "you seem [oblivious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oblivious) (as in "lacking active conscious knowledge") of what votes are for..." Feel pretty good description. I don't see how "oblivious" would be a derogatory  term or show poor manners and general lack of politeness and finesse with using language.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Perhaps you should join the English Language Stack Exchange and learn how to speak to fellow human beings then.  No one is playing victim here, but the irony of fighting accusations of hostility with actual hostility is too much fun to pass up.  By the way, you're the one who's switched to the victim card here.  See, everyone can play this game.

Comment: I know I have to work extra hard here, because I am dealing with programmers.  But @AlexeiLevenkov, if you're ever been to, say, a party or any other social event, calling someone oblivious, no matter how "objective" it is, is not going to help you deliver your point to the listener.

Comment: The question discussed in [this meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294325/372643) is actually a fairly good example of something closed rather quickly.

Comment: @Dave This isn't a party or a social event. It's a website for the dissemination of knowledge on a technical subject. On this website, if you are wrong, people come by and tell you about it.

Comment: Technical subject matter is not a license for sociopathic behavior.

Comment: @Dave: You are getting perilously close to invoking [Godwin's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godwin's_law). If you aren't actually already well past that stage... well, have fun.

Comment: @Dave Nobody is being a sociopath. Different social settings have different rules. Here on StackOverflow, we're creating content together and we care about that content. Unfortunately, that requires us to sometimes decide that particular content is (to give a simple description) bad.

Comment: Haha people are downvoting my old questions as we speak out of revenge.  That's pretty damn sociopathic (not to mention pathetic).

Comment: -1: Downvoting is not "hostile". And while I am all for giving a reason for downvotes (as you can tell from this comment), sometimes it is just redundant: Every new user is automatically given advice on how to ask questions. If users blatantly ignore that advice, I don't think it a productive use of my time to repeat it.

Comment: @Dave Sometimes when you make a post, people go look at your other posts. It's happened to me too. But I don't make assumptions about those voters or call them names. Instead, I went and improved the posts that got downvoted, because I realized they were bad.

Comment: ["downvotes are taken so damn personal..."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253230/839601)

Comment: "Haha people are downvoting my old questions as we speak out of revenge. That's pretty damn sociopathic": I took a look, you got 1 downvote and 2 (update, 3) upvotes today. That's some serious revenge, giving you 8 additional fake internet points...

Comment: What I truly don't understand here is that your comments are just as hostile and more derogatory than the ones you are chastising. If you think it's wrong, why are you doing it?

Comment: Yawn.​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @Radiodef, I agree, my comments got increasingly hostile after my answer was met with so much rudeness.  When you're contributing an opinion and you get "You're spewing nonsense" in response (I am not complaining about the downvotes), and then some joker is trying to argue that's a normal way to talk to people, that's a little much.  I'll be leaving Meta now because I have better things to do, but please know that if you show up at my party, call people oblivious and tell them that they're spewing nonsense just because they're wrong, I am throwing you the hell out.  Downvote away.

Comment: @Dave But this is not your party. This is not a social call. This is, for all intents and purposes, an objective collection and active summation of technical knowledge for programming. I was a beginner once. My first question in SO is easily answerable by "don't call y when you haven't instantiated y". But did I get booed out? Nope. Because my question was properly worded. This site is a meritocracy. That's why we have fake internet points. When you're new here, the **least** you can do is make your question worth the time of those who spend a fraction of their life helping strangers out.

Comment: And the way I see it, yes, this is a community. But same as any community, you don't come in with a severe breach of social protocol and not have us become hostile towards you. When you enter a habitat, **you blend in**, rather than have it bend to you.

Comment: I don't agree with the substance of this answer, but on the topic of helpful links in the comments, I do this all the time, and see it all the time. I wonder though whether a notice attached to questions that appears when they are downvoted, and only visible to the poster, would be useful. It would explain that downvotes are messages rather than hostility.

Comment: @Dave I fully agree to you to the hostile language used here. Even more, you cannot write "thanks" or "hello", this is edited out. Too human, I guess ;) You have no chance against the StackGods, ah, StackMods. At best, you can see it as a pure tool for asking questions, nothing more. If you want to connect to people, or give answers, or write more comprehensive articles, then better do it elsewhere. It's a pity. Technically, SO is by far the best system around, but the mods have lost connection to human touch.