# How exactly is this question off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, custom-close-reasons

[How do I use C# generic Dictionary like the Hashtable is used in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30246986/how-do-i-use-c-sharp-generic-dictionary-as-the-hashtable-in-java/)

It's a specific programming problem and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development. I feel that we're being unnecessarily discouraging to the person who asked it.

It isn't seeking debugging help, isn't non-reproducible, isn't about homework, doesn't ask for a resource recommendation, isn't about general computing, nor about tangential topics.

Further, the question is not trivially answerable. In fact, I'm not entirely sure that my answer is accurate. That's how non-trivial it is.

Comment: [This comment seems to be the reason](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30246986/how-do-i-use-c-sharp-generic-dictionary-as-the-hashtable-in-java/30247060#comment48594949_30246986)

Comment: Triviality may be reason to downvote, but definitely doesn't alone make something off topic.

Comment: I tend to agree, that doesn't seem to be an appropriate use of the custom off-topic close reasons. Just because something may seem simple doesn't immediately disqualify it as a question. I'll see what others have to say, but I'd lean towards removing that comment and reopening the question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The Help Center does not require a question be non-trivial to be [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It may indicate that the asker didn't do their research or it may make the question not useful, but it doesn't make the question off topic.

I'm not arguing that this particular question is trivial, I'm saying that it's *irrelevant* whether it's trivial or not. It's on topic.

Comment: Just as a note: the help center may not require it, but I'm certainly going to vote to close extremely trivial questions if they're something a basic language tutorial could have answered. SO should be used once you've at least made an effort to find an answer yourself, and working your way through any of the many available basic tutorial sites should be part of that effort. I have no desire to see this site inundated with the millions of trivial questions from new student assignments like "How do I add two numbers in Visual Basics?" or "How do I count from 1 to 10 in C and print it out?".

Comment: Related to @KenWhite's point: [Has a consensus been reached on whether or not some questions are too simple?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108006)

Comment: @KenWhite - I hope my answer isn't seen as an argument that trivial questions are necessarily _good_ questions.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Thanks for that link; I'd forgotten that question (and Jeff's answer to it, which I think makes the point I was making above).

Comment: @KenWhite: that's my view as well. This is a question asking how to use a dictionary, that's 30 seconds on MSDN. No effort has been put in the question whatsoever.

Comment: @BSMP: I didn't take it that way. But there's no point in allowing trivial questions to hang around and collect downvotes if they can be quickly closed and then deleted. There's no value in keeping them around; the poster isn't going to improve them (after all, the effort to do so would be more than it would have taken to find it before posting).

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: Just to make it clear, my comment to this answer isn't intended to reflect in any way on the topic of the question above; it's strictly related to this answer's content. I don't want it to be misconstrued otherwise (in either direction, pro or con).

Answer (score 26):

I'm going to quote Shaun's comment here, because it is exactly what I was thinking when I first went to the question:

> Saying that it's trivial isn't fair nor realistic and is unnecessarily
>   discouraging.

I know a bit about Android to the point where almost every question here on those topics seems "trivial".

I know where to look for resources, so most of the questions on this site seem as if the OP has not bothered to look. I also know what resources are out of date, or refer to old versions of the OS.

I've recently picked up the HTML/CSS/JavaScript stack and for the first week I felt like a complete noob!

Not only did I not know the languages, or how they really fitted together; but **I also didn't know what questions to ask, or what I didn't know.**

---

It is at that point where supposedly "trivial" questions are actually a gold mine of information.

We must not forget where we came from - remember that the skills we take for granted on a day-to-day are actually very valuable, and in some of our cases, we are much more "expert" than we choose to see.

What seems like a ridiculously simple question to you as a developer in that field, may be a road-block to a newer programmer (on that platform).

Comment: You've understood me perfectly.