# Same answer, different questions

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

I posted the same answer for both [PyQt5 : The DLL load failed : the specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36666225/pyqt5-the-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found) and [DLL load failed when importing PyQt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863505/dll-load-failed-when-importing-pyqt5).

My answer might solve both problems. However, there are **other** possible solutions and they are **different** for both questions.

My answer was deleted by ChrisF as being a duplicate answer and 
he suggested I should mark one question a duplicate of the other.

I don't think that's right, the questions are different, they just happen to have the same answer (among others). According to [What to do with same answers from one user on multiple questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270841/what-to-do-with-same-answers-from-one-user-on-multiple-questions) there's not even a problem with the same answer to multiple questions.

Should I actually mark one (randomly chosen?) question as a duplicate?

Comment: There are extremely simple questions that could have the exactly the same answer; but more often than not, if an answer can be copied verbatim from one question to the other; it is a very clear sign that the second one is a duplicate from the first (it has an answer that solves the problem, and could have been found by researching more). The duplicate message will help people who find the second question to get to right answer in the first one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the same answer imply that the questions should be closed as duplicate? - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292329/does-the-same-answer-imply-that-the-questions-should-be-closed-as-duplicate)

Answer (score 3):

If the same solution works, then they are pretty much duplicates. And if they have other solutions, that might mean they could also be interchangeable.

So, closing as a duplicate will help new viewers, to find solutions on both questions and will give them more choices. It will not harm either questions, so that won't be a problem.

Instead of random, just mark the latest question as a duplicate.

Comment: Unfortunately the one where my answer was deleted is the newer one.

Comment: @AndreKR, as it should have. You mark the newer one as a dupe of the older one. So you only need the older answer in the end.

Comment: Sorry, the *older* one. :)

Comment: Meh. Sometimes the newer one have better quality answers, or the question itself is of better quality, or just some random luck on which one gets discovered first to be a duplicate). Generally, I don't think it matters much which one is the dup target and which is the dup flagpost. The idea is that anyone finding either may end up in the right place. As long as useful knowledge isn't lost, all is good.